# $(this) in JavaScript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I'm trying to use the Javascript module pattern for the first time to organize my code. I understand the how "this" works here but cannot figure out how $(this) works. For example, the code below,
**$(this).addClass('video-active');** in "chooseVideo" function, I want to apply  addClass only for the clicked element. But it does not work. Could anybody give me some advice? Thank you!

```
;(function() {
   'use strict';
   if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'function') {
     return;
   }
   var $ = jQuery;

   var video = {
     init: function() {
       this.cacheDom();
       this.bindEvents();
       this.render();
     },
     cacheDom: function() {
       this.$el = $('#videoWrap');
       this.$button = this.$el.find('.video');
     },
     render: function() {

     },
     bindEvents: function() {
       this.$button.bind('click', this.chooseVideo.bind(this));
     },
     chooseVideo: function(e) {
       e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
       this.$button.removeClass('video-active');
       $(this).addClass('video-active');
     }
   };

   video.init();

})();
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass('video-active');` should not work

Comment: `$(this)` is the standard way of wrapping something like a DOM element in the jQuery handler.

Comment: @tadman But `this` is not a DOM element

Comment: It better be if you're calling `addClass` on it. Remember `this` changes wildly from function to function.

Comment: And you do not know who you are talking too... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use bind, you are changing the context of `this`

So you will need to use the event object to get what was clicked.

```
chooseVideo: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
   this.$button.removeClass('video-active');
   $(e.target).addClass('video-active');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling this issue for a few hours! You save my day! Really appreciate it!